# Loading DLL in Java applet

Tags: java, applet

I have a web interface, in which users will fill in some data, will digitally sign it (using a USB token) and will print it with an old matrix printer.
To handle this I intend to write a Java applet, which loads a DLL from the server (to avoid installation on client's machine). This DLL will then access the USB token, do the signing and handle the printing (there are some particularities).
Since I do not have much experience with Java technologies and if I can do this at all, I would be grateful if someone can point me in the right direction. Should I use JNI or JavaWebServer or maybe some other technology?

Comment: *"I intend to write a Java applet.. (which uses DLLs)"*  Therein lies a path to madness.  Make it a free-floating desktop app. launched using [JWS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) for quicker development time and less maintenance (and to perhaps retain your sanity).

Comment: "Make it a free-floating desktop app". Should this free-floating app be installed on teh user's PC?

Comment: No, Java Web Start applications are downloaded for execution. They work more or less like an applet, but don't execute in the browser.

Comment: A JWS app. is as 'web based' as an applet.  The only difference (beyond the nightmares applets produce) is that the applet is crammed in a web page.

Comment: *"Should this free-floating app be installed on teh user's PC?"*  Yes and no.  Both applets **and** JWS apps. ***are*** downloaded and installed locally.  Both methods of download/installation are relatively 'invisible' to the end user.

Comment: It seems that Java Web Start is what I am looking for. Thank you

Comment: Just had a look at the Java Web Start. It says "The Java Web Start software is launched automatically, when a Java application using Java Web Start technology is downloaded for the first time". Does that mean that he application I am going to download and run must be written in Java?

Comment: Since Java Web Start works with Java apps only and I want to be able to open LPT port and do stuff with the printer, I cannot use this. So back to square one-JAva applet with JNI and a DLL

Comment: Tip:  Add @SJuan76 (or whoever - the `@` is important) to *notify them* of a new comment.  BTW - your last comment reads like nonsense to me.  A JWS app. can use natives just as well as an applet. No, (considers) better, given the JNLP (JWS launch file) can partition the downloads by OS (e.g. .dll for Windows, .so for *nix).

Comment: *"Does that mean that he application I am going to download and run must be written in Java?"*  What do you think applets are written in, JavaScript?

Comment: I thought that JWS would allow you to download any sort of application (native, Java etc.) and run it (given the right sort of credentials/permissions/signatures etc). Also, since I need access to LPT1 and cannot do it in Java, I have to use native code.